# UTF-8 characters into c# webserver

Tags: c#, html, .net, webserver

I have a simply C# webserver and firstly I want to show random text from array. I see the text into console and into webpage but the problem is utf8 - some Polish characters are in ACSII but only in webpage. In console everything is OK.

Here is my code to show a random text:

```
  internal class Program
{


    public static string SendResponse(HttpListenerRequest request)
    {
        String[] tablica = new String[12];
        tablica[0] = "Życie jest jak pudełko czekoladek, nigdy nie wiesz, co ci się trafi.";
        tablica[1] = "Na tym świecie jeden człowiek jest nikim, a innego świata nie ma.";
        tablica[2] = "Jeśli chcesz rozśmieszyć Boga, to powiedz mu, co planujesz.";
        tablica[3] = "Wszyscy kiedyś umrzemy. Lecz nie wszyscy wiedzą, jak żyć.";
        tablica[4] = "Trudno być złym, kiedy świat ma do zaoferowania tyle piękna.";
        tablica[5] = "W życiu musisz być rekinem, jeśli nie chcesz żeby dopadły cię inne rekiny.";
        tablica[6] = "Życia nie można wybrać, ale można z niego coś zrobić.";
        tablica[7] = "Ludzie budują za dużo murów, a za mało mostów.";
        tablica[8] = "To smutne, że głupcy są tacy pewni siebie, a ludzie rozsądni tacy pełni wątpliwości.";
        tablica[9] = "Wielkość człowieka polega na jego postanowieniu, żeby być silniejszym niż warunki czasu i życia.";
        tablica[10] = "Rób, co możesz, w miejscu, jakim jesteś i z tym, co masz.";
        tablica[11] = "Dopiero w samotności człowiek jest naprawdę sobą.";

        Random rand = new Random();

        Console.WriteLine(tablica[rand.Next(0, 11)]);
        //return string.Format("<HTML><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);
        return "Motto na dziś: \n" + tablica[rand.Next(12)];

    }



    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ws = new WebServer(SendResponse, "http://localhost:8080/test/");
        ws.Run();
        Console.WriteLine("WebServer is started. Press any button to stop.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        ws.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't define a encoding in your html response, this way it is assumed that you send ascii

Comment: So what code need I to use?

Comment: `string.Format("<!DOCTYPE HTML><HTML><HEAD><meta charset='utf-8'/></HEAD><BODY>My web page.<br>{0}</BODY></HTML>", DateTime.Now);`
Should do the trick

Comment: But as you can see this line is in comment. I dont use it. Im using:

return "Motto na dziś: \n" + tablica[rand.Next(12)];

Comment: Side note: declare `rand` outside of routine, you don't need to keep creating new instances of `Random`. Also no need to create `tablica` every single time either.

Comment: true but you forget that this way the browser does only see a string, at least you need headers which say which encoding to use, which isnt possible when you just send a plain string. that's why i suggested the templated approach.

Comment: I used that code before in Java and it works. Now U need to use it but in C# and I have utf8 problem :(

Comment: i would suggest you take a look at the responses, especially the headers, of your java application and try to reproduce that with your c# application.

Comment: I tried but ihave used Spring Framework. I thought I am only have to rewrite array and return function to show my random Text :(